# Is it possible to clone not a repository but a project in bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

I want to work on a project on Bitbucket but it's divided into I don't know how many repositories, maybe 100.  It seems quite tedious to have to individually clone 100 repositories and yet all the googling I have done is all about how to clone a repository not a project.  The project is here

https://bitbucket.org/shcdemo/workspace/projects/EAR

And I would need all of the repositories that it is composed of but I want to make sure there isn't an easy to download all repositories with one command.

Comment: If there are 100 repositories necessary to to work on something, then it wouldn't surprise me if someone scripted it for you already. Or maybe there is a base repo with submodules?

Comment: well, I'm going to ask him anyway